# Stitching turtle & opencv video windows together

Tags: opencv, video-streaming, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, opencv-stitching

I have a program which opens turtle window & opencv video window together. I want to adjust 2 windows together or rather stitch them horizontally. How can I do this?

```
class PrettyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PrettyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(500, 100, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('')
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Please select video', self)

        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.SingleBrowse)
        btn.move(150, 200)
        self.show()


    def SingleBrowse(self):
        video_path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Single File',"./")
        
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
        preprocess = preprocessing(config,"Occupancy Grid Matrix") # this makes turtle window having ogm
        while(True):

                ret,frame = video.read()
                if frame is None:
                    break
                cv2.imshow("",frame)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I want turtle window & opencv window to be displayed together in 1 window rather than adjusting 2 windows manually to be in center of screen.

Comment: Hi - that's great.  Where's the program?  Please see [ask].

Comment: ask specific questions. it is difficult to visualize what you mean. If you want to stitch, there are already existing oepncv code sample

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai please check snippet

Comment: @rayryeng Please check the snippet